# What is the algorithm used to implement numpy.ascontiguousarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an big 2D-array F-contiguous e.g.

```
>> a = np.random.random((10000000, 10))
>> b = a[:, [1,3,5,7,9]]
>> b.flag()
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

What is the algorithm behind

```
>> t = time.time(); c = np.ascontiguousarray(b); print(time.time() - t)
>> 0.1587984561920166
```

If I implement the same thing just using simple value copy, it's over 0.6 seconds. I tried to find in the [multiarray](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray) implementation, but cannot find the relevant source code.

Comment: What do you mean by "just using simple value copy"? When I compare `numpy.ascontiguousarray(b)` to `b.copy()`, `b.copy()` wins (by a very slight margin).

Comment: You should never do serious benchmarks with `time.time`. When I use `timeit` I get `b.copy()` being slightyfaster.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `ascontiguous` is:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='C', ndmin=1)
```

code for `np.copy` is

```
return array(a, order=order, copy=True)
```

`a.copy` method is compiled so we can't trace it in the same way, but it probably behaves like `np.copy`.

So if the source is already `C` contiguous, `ascontiguous` does nothing to it.  If `F` contiguous the results should be (nearly) identical.

Comment: Thanks, but what I was really looking for was the C code behind the `array`  implementation. There are just too much layers so I could not figure out which one corresponds to this.

Comment: Usually we think of algorithm as a more abstract description than the C code details.  But, few of us have dug into the details of `np.array` or `.copy`.  I suspect that you want to know how `numpy` reorders the elements of your array to make it `C` contiguous (as opposed to the whole `make a new array` mechanism.  If so then your question should focus on that.  My suspicion is that after going through several layers of decision making, `ascontiguous` ends up using the same `c` function to copy values to a new array.

Comment: Yes. Have you found which function it is? Based on different keyword arguments, such as `dtype`, `copy`, `order`, `subok`, `ndmin`, different functions are used. I just don't know which is the final function to look at.

Comment: No I haven't dug into `numpy` code in that depth.  It might help if you explained why you want to know this?  Is it just the end result that matters, or are you trying to replicate the action in your own C code?